# Voting fund 6 not working

Tags: voting

Can not register for fund 6. In adalight it says [enter link description here](https://ibb.co/njBjVkR)

Registration for fund 5 voting is closed, and fund 6 is not shown.

Comment: Did you already update the app and clear both cache and storage?

Answer (score 1):

Registration for fund6 is now closed, last call was on Oct 4 - 11AM UTC.

As @Aron Neewart said, you probably need to update your app if you don't see fund6. Anyway, now is too late to register, do that for the next fund